# Visual Studio extensibility VS namespace

Tags: visual-studio, vs-extensibility

I'm beginning to dive into the world of Visual Studio extensions (VSIX) and many of the examples I am seeing are in the VS namespace. As an example `VS.Documents.GetActiveDocumentViewAsync()`. I have the extension development workload installed and have generated a basic working toolwindow example but I cannot figure out where this VS namespace comes from, as the system currently does not recognize it. Is this from a nuget package somewhere, or perhaps an extension that I need to install?

Answer (score 0):

For those who come hunting in this corner, the answer I have found is that in order to enable the VS namespace, it is necessary to use one of the VSIX templates denoted as "(Community)." Only then will it work. AFAICT there is no nuget pkg, etc. which inherently enables this.